# Recommended authenticated stream cipher for minimum overhead?

Tags: stream-cipher, hmac, authenticated-encryption, ctr, integrity

I'm running my TCP/IP protocol secured by encrypting each packet with AES128/CBC, bundling a SHA256 HMAC over that packet.

This causes quite a bit of space overhead for small packets, so at first I was thinking of running AES in CTR-mode and still use the HMAC, but it would be much better to run some sort of stream cipher with integrated authentication.

What are my best options?

Edit:

I should mention that failing an integrity check will always disconnect a connection.

This means re-negotiating the encryption keys, which gives each new connection a new encryption and signing key.

In other words, make a wrong guess and the keys are reset. Even with a small integrity checksum, guessing right to sustain an exchange appears to be a hard problem.

Comment: You will still have the same overhead with an authenticated stream cipher. They still have a message fingerprint, the strength of authenticated modes of encryption is in safely coupling encryption and authentication. AES-CTR *is* a stream cipher, by the way. If your packets are so small, are you sure you need to authenticate them all as they are received? Perhaps you could batch the authentication step if the packets are sent at a high rate, to alleviate the space overhead issue?

Comment: @Thomas yes, of course AES-CTR is a stream cipher. In order to avoid trivial bit-flipping of the packets, some integrity checking is necessary. As I understand it there are several ways to put that on top a stream cipher without having a separate HMAC or similar as checksum.

Comment: Yes, of course. But, no, a MAC always requires extra information. Think about it - if you have X bits of plaintext to encrypt and authenticate, and Y bits of output, at the very least X = Y to ensure correct decryption (pigeonhole principle) which leaves nothing for authentication. So Y > X. So, no, any authentication mechanism will always add a few bytes of overhead to store the fingerprint. So your options are in making the fingerprint smaller (not ideal for obvious reasons) or authenticating more data per fingerprint.

Comment: If it were possible to have zero authentication overhead, authenticated encryption schemes would already be doing it. You won't find your solution at this low a level, you need to go up a notch and design your system around minimizing overhead.

Comment: Yes, but the question is how to minimize the data needed for the fingerprinting. For example as a naive suggestion, one could envision extracting only part of the HMAC for smaller packets making some rule that for a packet of size n the HMAC is max n / 2 bytes long - by taking only that many bytes from the HMAC, starting from the end or front.

Comment: That's a bad idea. Using only parts of the HMAC is a loss of integrity. Assuming the attacker knows the message is only 1 byte long. He still can not test these $2^8$ possibilities and find a correct HMAC , because he does not know $k$. If you use only part of the HMAC, his chance of random guessing went up to non-neglectible probability.

Comment: @tylo I wasn't seriously suggesting a 1 byte HMAC. What I was wondering was what the good ways are of reducing the size of the extra data needed for integrity. From what I understand then some modes, like CCM offer different MAC sizes, (CCM has a smallest size of 4 bytes). Also, see my clarification regarding how the protocol works in terms of integrity checks.

Comment: To answer your question: There is no way to keep integrity and reducing the size of the MAC. 4 byte MAC means $\frac{1}{2^{32}}$ probability for a correct guess. This is independent of the actual algorithms used and is the upper bound for it. For almost any algorithm, "meet in the middle" works just fine, which changes the computational time from $2^{32}$ to $2^{16}$ time and $2^{16}$ space.

Comment: Small correction: Meet in the middle transforms the complexity from $O(2^n)$ time and $O(1)$ space to $O(2^{n/2})$ and $O(2^{n/2})$ space, where n denotes the bitlength of the MAC.

Comment: @tylo I understand, but isn't the necessary security of the HMAC also dependent on the protocol. If, for example, a failed HMAC checksum forces a re-negotiation of encryption and signing keys, then you'd basically have to randomly check keys until you get a valid HMAC. And that just gives you the ability to change the bits of a single packet. If the protocol blacklists someone for 5 seconds for violating a HMAC, you have a 50% chance to find a match within 340 years. Or am I doing the maths wrong?

Comment: Well yes, you can do that and your math is almost correct (680 years with $5 \times 2^{32}$, mean value of a geometric distribution, if you consider each trial independent of the previous). However, your approach has a huge downside: If you do re-negotiation or blocking for a certain time, your protocol gets extremely vulnerable to denial of service attacks. And even for regular execution you will run into problems, as the underlying protocols do not guarantee correct transmission of packages - it's just as close to 100% as they can get.

Comment: There might be some kind of trade-off here, between resilience against DOS and security. But on the other hand.... the IP header is 16+ byte, the TCP header is 16+ byte, the ethernet frame is 30 byte, and then you have your actual message. Even for short packages, this is not that much of overhead (20 byte for SHA-1 HMAC, 32 byte for SHA256)

Comment: @tylo Each trial should be independent since the we mix in new nonces to generate keys from. How do you figure the DoS attack here? I'm only blocking that particular IP for 5 seconds, and only for login.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I corrected the math. About the DoS: It's not meant to block the server for everyone. It's about blocking the server for a specific person or interrupting connections. And since you need to modify just 1 package for every potential user every 5 seconds, you could just target everyone trying to connect to the the server. But as I said, this can also cause problems in regular usage, if an undetected bitflip occurs on the lower levels of the transport protocol. The "only for login" part wasn't mentioned before, I think.

Comment: @tylo I don't see how that would be practical. If you already can insert yourself between players an the server, then you could perform that DoS by simply dropping their connections. Just to clarify the 'only for login' - if you connect with your client, then someone tries to connect *with the same IP* and violates protocol, then a block will be put in place for new logins, but yours are unaffected. In practice it's also a very minor inconvenience - it will appear as a dropped connection to the client which then will do an automatic reconnect after 5s. So it just looks like a slow connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked [the same question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/37490/971) over on the IT Security site.
Please don't cross-post.  It is frowned upon, under the rules these sites operate.

Here is what you should be doing:

- Truncate the MAC tag to an acceptable length.  You will need to choose a length that provides a suitable tradeoff between packet size vs. security against forgery.  I suggest you use an authenticated encryption scheme.  See [my answer on the other site](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/37578/971) for details.
- For additional robustness, you could include in the MAC a running hash of all prior packets.  This way, if anyone tampers with a single packet, then it will invalidate all subsequent MAC tags.  This may or may not add security, depending upon the application.  However, it can't hurt: it doesn't increase the length of the packet at all, so it is free, and in some cases it might help stop some attacks (if they require forging a packet in the middle of a stream).

  For example, suppose you use a 16-bit MAC tag.  This is too short to prevent an attacker from forging a packet by sheer blind luck: if the attacker sends a forged packet with a random 16-bit tag, then it will be accepted with probability $1/2^{16}$.  Therefore, an attacker can get a single forged packet accepted, by trying $2^{16}$ times until they succeed.  In some applications, that's bad enough that the application is irrecoverably broken.  But in others, forging a single packet is not devastating in itself.  In the latter case, we can proceed to ask: after the attacker successfully forged a single packet, what happens next?  If you don't add a running hash, then the attacker can allow the rest of the packets to flow unimpeded, and the connection will continue.  In particular, it's possible that neither endpoint will notice anything has gone awry.  But if you use a running hash, then there's no way the attacker can allow the conversation to continue.  If the attacker forges one packet then allows all subsequent packets to flow unimpeded, the recipient will reject all subsequent packets, as they don't have a matching running hash.  There's no way for the attacker to recover and repair the connection so it can continue at length -- so a successful forgery inevitably leads to denial of service shortly thereafter.  This increases the chances that a successful attack will be noticed, and makes it harder to carry out attacks that require multiple successful forgeries.  So, in some applications, it may make some attacks harder (no guarantees, but it might just help).

And again, you probably really ought to be looking much more seriously at TLS or DTLS.  Writing your own packet format is a recipe for trouble.

Comment: I know I shouldn't cross-post, but the type of answers differ widely, so I couldn't resist it. As for the running MAC, I already bundle a counter with the packet (in the encrypted data) to avoid replay attacks. I'm guessing that either: a) putting the counter in the encrypted data or b) adding the counter to the HMAC of c) keep a running hash would be fairly equivalent, or?

Comment: But a counter would be unnecessary if I instead run in a streaming mode like CTR, right?

Comment: [@Nuoji, Oops, I just realized my last comment had a massive typo.  I'll re-print it, but this time with a correction.  See also my edited answer.]  No, a counter is not equivalent to a running hash. I'm suggesting a running hash as a hardening measure, so that it's hard to forge a single packet and then allow the other packets through unchanged. A counter doesn't provide that same benefit.

Answer (score 3):

There aren't any known attacks on the [PRFness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function) of HMAC-SHA256 better than brute force.

(So you can truncate that MAC to length L where $\:\:\frac1{2^L}+\epsilon\:\:$ is an acceptable risk of forgery.)

To reduce the impact of a forgery without making the ciphertext any longer, one should use a

[format-preserving encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-Preserving_Encryption) (FPE) scheme that is secure against one query to the encryption

oracle and one query to the decryption oracle, which are not necessarily made in that order. $\;\;\;$ 

Choose either $\; [b_{client} = 0 \: \text{ and } \: b_{server} = 1] \:$ or $ \: [b_{client} = 1 \: \text{ and } \: b_{server} = 0] \;$.

Let $\;\; \operatorname{pL} \: : \: \{0,\hspace{-0.03 in}1,\hspace{-0.03 in}2,\hspace{-0.03 in}3,...\} \: \to \: \{0,\hspace{-0.03 in}1,\hspace{-0.03 in}2,\hspace{-0.03 in}3,...\} \;\;$ be an injective function that can be inverted

efficiently enough. $\;\;\;\;$ For the sentence two after this one to be possible, you will also need that

for all $m$, $\: m\leq \operatorname{pL}(m) \:\:$. $\;\;\;\;$ Let $\;\; \operatorname{rL} \: : \: \{0,\hspace{-0.03 in}1,\hspace{-0.03 in}2,\hspace{-0.03 in}3,...\} \: \to \: \{0,\hspace{-0.03 in}1,\hspace{-0.03 in}2,\hspace{-0.03 in}3,...\} \;\;$ be a function that

can be computed efficiently enough. $\;\;\;\;$ Let $\;\; \operatorname{pad}_{\hspace{.01 in}m}\hspace{-0.01 in} \: : \: \{0,\hspace{-0.03 in}1\}^m \hspace{-0.01 in} \times \{0,\hspace{-0.03 in}1\}^{\operatorname{rL}(m)} \: \to \: \{0,\hspace{-0.03 in}1\}^{\operatorname{pL}(m)}$

be a sequence of injective functions that can be computed efficiently enough and satisfies

$[message$ can be efficiently computed from $\:\operatorname{pad}_{\operatorname{length}(message)}\hspace{-0.02 in}(message,\hspace{-0.02 in}randomness)]$.

$\operatorname{unpad}_{\operatorname{length}(message)}\hspace{-0.02 in}(\operatorname{pad}(message,\hspace{-0.02 in}randomness)) \: = \: message$

For all other values of $x$, $\;\; \operatorname{unpad}(x) \: = \hspace{.08 in} \perp \;\;\;$.

$\operatorname{Enc}(key,party,packetnumber,plaintext,randomness)$

$=$
$\operatorname{FPEencrypt}(\operatorname{HMAC}(key,b_{party}||\hspace{.02 in}packetnumber),\operatorname{pad}(plaintext,randomness))$

$\operatorname{Dec}(key,party,packetnumber,ciphertext)$

$=$
$\operatorname{unpad}(\operatorname{FPEdecrypt}(\operatorname{HMAC}(key,(1-b_{party})||\hspace{.02 in}packetnumber),ciphertext))$

As long as each party only encrypts and decrypts once each for each $packetnumber$, a feasible adversary will have probability $\:\: \frac1{2^{\operatorname{pL}(m)-(m+\operatorname{rL}(m))}}+\epsilon\:\:$ of violating integrity for each submitted ciphertext

of length $\operatorname{pL}(m) \:$ (and a ciphertext whose length is not in $\:\operatorname{range}(\operatorname{pL})\;$ will always decrypt to $\perp$).

> Furthermore, if the parameters are such that that probability is noticeable, then the decryptions
>   
>   of ciphertexts with length $\operatorname{pL}(m)$ that violate integrity will be computationally indistinguishable
>   
>   from independent samples from the following distributions for each such ciphertext:
>   
>   if the indicated $party$ did *not* output a ciphertext for that $packetnumber$, then uniform on $\{0,\hspace{-0.03 in}1\}^m$
>   
>   else, the plaintext used by $party$ for that $packetnum$ with probability $\frac{2^{\operatorname{rL}(m)}-1}{2^{m+\operatorname{rL}(m)}-1}$,
>   
>   and each other member of $\{0,\hspace{-0.03 in}1\}^m$ with probability $\; \frac{2^{\operatorname{rL}(m)}}{2^{m+\operatorname{rL}(m)}-1} \:\:$.

Comment: What way would that be?

Comment: Ergh. No offense, but I find multi-character variables to be incredibly ugly. Isn't $\operatorname{length}(message)$ so much less appealing than $\ell(m)$? Also, $\{0,1,2,3,\dots\}$ could be specified as $\mathbb{N}_0$.